# Updating a column with another column's values in python but only NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm trying to use the .update() function to update the values of one column (B) with values from another column (C) in the same dataframe. However, I would like to only replace the values in column B that are NaN. I have tried using the overwrite = False argument but I keep getting an error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [400, np.nan, 600],
                   'C': [32,54,300]})
df['B'].update(df['C'], overwrite = False) 
df

#Output:
#TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overwrite'

#The intended output I'm looking for is this: 
    A   B       C
0   1   400.0   32
1   2   54.0    54
2   3   600.0   300
```

However, when I use the update.() function to update the whole dataset, the overwrite argument works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [400, np.nan, 600],
                   'C': [32,54,300]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],
                       'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df, overwrite = False) 
df

#Output: 
    A   B       C
0   1   400.0   32
1   2   5.0     54
2   3   600.0   300
```

Does the overwrite argument just not work when updating a column with another column in the same dataframe? Would like to check how I might go about updating a column with another column's values but only overwriting values that are NaN. Thank you so much!

Comment: To answer your questions and this is pretty important.  pd.DataFrame.update is not the same as pd.Series.update.  There is no `overwrite` parameter in pd.Series.update.  You must know the object type you are working with.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question and this is pretty important. [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas-dataframe-update) is not the same as [`pd.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html#pandas-series-update). There is no `overwrite` parameter in pd.Series.update. You must know the object type you are working with.

Let's use `fillna`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['C'])
```

Output:

```
   A      B    C
0  1  400.0   32
1  2   54.0   54
2  3  600.0  300
```

Or mask, or where, or a few other ways... combine_first.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comment only in [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) we have `overwrite` parameter and `df['B'].update` return a [`pandas.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) and we can not use `overwrite`.

You can use [`pandas.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
msk = df['B'].isnull()
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(msk, df['C'])
# Or
df['B'] = np.where(msk, df['C'], df['B'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   A      B    C
0  1  400.0   32
1  2   54.0   54
2  3  600.0  300
```

Comment: Maybe good to mention that `numpy.where` changes dtype to `object` when `pandas`  dtype `Int64` (nullable integer) is used, which is not the case when `pandas.Series.mask` is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [400, np.nan, 600], 'C': [32, 54, 300]})

df.update(df.rename(columns={'B':'C', 'C':'B'}), overwrite = False) 

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A      B    C
0  1  400.0   32
1  2   54.0   54
2  3  600.0  300
```